# Dart factory (constructor) vs. static method; e.g., why is int.parse() not a factory constructor?

Tags: constructor, dart, static-methods, factory, factory-method

The **Dart Style Guide** recommends using [*constructors instead of static methods to create instances*](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/#do-use-constructors-instead-of-static-methods-to-create-instances), given that "*named constructors and **factory constructors** in Dart give you all of the flexibility of static methods in other languages, while still allowing the callsite to appear like a regular constructor invocation*".

Is there a technical reason then, for having declared `int.parse()` and `double.parse()` as static methods rather than factory constructors?

More generally, what would be the guidelines for choosing to write a factory constructor over a static (factory) method in Dart?

Comment: Yes, that does seem a bit inconsistent. `new int.fromString()` would make more sense from that perspective. Although `int.parse()` feels more natural.

Comment: This may very well be another special treatment for performance purposes, but that's really just wild guessing.

Comment: @MarioP: Yea, I guess that makes sense. However, I would have hoped that the compiler was good enough at optimizing that such special treatment wasn't necessary.

Comment: @ronag Turns out I was wrong anyway. "Feels more natural" is actually much closer ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After digging around in Google Groups for a while, I did in fact find an official explanation for it: [Link to Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/m_kjxV8k5s0/IUg2eKzesQUJ)

For archive purposes, here the text as quoted from the link:

> I thought about making it a constructor, but it didn't feel right for int or double values.
>
> I see "parse" as a utility function more than a constructor, probably because int and double don't really have constructors otherwise. You don't create an integer, you discover it.
>
> Also, currently the only way to check if a string is a number literal is to call parse and see if it throws (but I'm not entirely satisfied with that!), and I don't like constructors that throw on anything but programming errors.
>
> And you don't have to write "new" in front of it this way, for no particular gain.
>
> There is no single hard reason that makes it obviously not a constructor, but a bunch of smaller issues that together make me prefer it as a static function.

So much for my "performance purposes" theory. Oh well.

Comment: Ok so since Dart 2.0 where the use of new is discouraged there is really no difference then.